# INSERT with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, insert, foreign-keys

I searched about it first, but I didn't find what I really want.
Ok, I'm not an expert in mySQL, therefore I'm with a little problem to solve.

So, I have 2 tables: MATERIALS and ORDERS as below:

Orders:
`Id_O | Client | material | etc..`

Materials:
`Id_M | Id_O`

Note: 1-to many relationship.

I have the table "orders" to register all the data.
A second table "materials" is to identify the materials that belongs to the same ID, what means that I will have the materials: 'material1', 'material2', etc.. for the order with ID='1'.
Then I want to show that info as a list.

- OT_1 Material_1 - description1
- OT_1 Material_2 - description2
  ...

So, to collect these data, How can I make the queries to work fine? In fact, it's my doubt.
Because when I'm submitting the order, I want to be able to register 2 or 3 materials at the same time, for the same ID as I said before.

Thanks.

Comment: Where will you be selecting them from? Order can't already have the material right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible insert into your materials table after you insert into the Orders table. Yes, you can make an insert with a select.

Comment: Selecting materails can be static, is not a problem because are few.
But I can make the insert of 3 values (example) at the same time? for the same ID as I refered.

Comment: So... what is in the orders table, material field?  A list?

Comment: orders table has everything about the order such as id_ot, material, client etc.. and I thought in create another table 'materials' to make the relationship with the id's. In order to have different materials for the same order ID (id_ot)

Comment: For order with ID = '1' I will have: material1, material2 and material3. And each material has a different id to identify as well.

Comment: This example confuses me. Please update the question and put an example order with materials as it currently looks.

Comment: Updated! I think that now is well explained.

Comment: Where's the code that you refer to as `submitting the order` because _(I assume)_ you want to follow that code immediately with new code to populate the Materials table?

Comment: Ok, I have the normal query to insert all data. And my problem is how to insert different materials at the same time (same ID). 
On orders table just the ID, and on materials table as I put on example: ID_MATERIAL, ID_OT (foreign key) and description.
Can I use a loop or something on VALUES ? With one button I populate the id's for the materials table.

Comment: I think that is not so confusing, just might be not logic or the best solution.
In theory simple as: Make a query with one ID that has different values for one field (attribute).

Comment: I think there is a language barrier here. Is your question asking how to MIGRATE existing data, or how to insert a new order as that order is made on a site?

Comment: Nothing about migrate.. Just inserting a new order, with different materials (different values for the same field), what will produce different rows.
Submit form on webpage to: INSERT INTO orders(id_ot,client,material, blabla...) and then make an assoc to the table MATERIALS (id_mat,id_ot,material_description).

Ok, I can put some button to make the second part after submit the order, on close button or something.

Comment: Main point is: How to make multiple insert values in one query !!!

Comment: Your database is wrong. There should be no orders.material! if there is a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: Material is just on the other table (MATERIALS)

Comment: `Main point is: How to make multiple insert values in one query !!!` - ok here is how you insert more than one value:: **INSERT INTO MATERIALS (Id_O) SELECT Id_O FROM ORDERS WHERE ...** _You need to share code if you want more specific help_

Comment: Thank you! I figured out a solution with your query!
Now I have another doubt, can I split on inserting?
For example, I have this field (varchar): val1,val2,val3 in table 'Orders' and when I insert in table 'materials' I want to have in separated rows, each one with its ID. It is possible? Using explode or a split way. 1-val1, 2-val2 , etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a 1-to many relationship (1 order can have many materials) then you would get your orderID and your array of materials and loop over it.

You should not, in this configuration, have "material" in the "orders" table however.

I need to see an example of the data in orders, but assuming a list:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM orders');
$insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO materials VALUES (?,?)'); 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $materials = explode(",", $row['material']);
    foreach($materials as $material) {
         $insert->execute(array($row["id_O"], $material));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, is 1-to many relationship as you said.
By the way, the material description can be just in the orders table. Is not necessary to be in materials table. Or how you suggest me?

Comment: It's not good DMBS design to duplicate data, so it should be either in one place or the other.

Comment: Yes I agree, I put just in the table orders. Materials table I created just to try to make the relationship between them and make the association with the ID's

Comment: Is there any scripting language in use here?

Comment: If you are using PHP, this is much simpler.

Comment: I thought in use a loop on values when I'm inserting.

Comment: Ok, one question. What I put on values? question mark on fields?

Comment: The questions marks are literal, they are used in PDO prepare statements: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers 

The data goes into `$insert->execute(array($row["id_O"], $material));`

Comment: not the best fetch:
gives me this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute()

Comment: The example I'm giving uses PDO, not mysqli. Modify as necessary for your db connection.  Also, this answer assumed that material was a list in the orders table that you wanted to migrate.... because that is what your original question layout showed. Very frustrating if you make this up as we go along.